# android passing datahelper between intents

Tags: android

I get "Application did not close the cursor or database object that was opened here" error so I decided to pass datahelper between intents rather than close/open database for every intent..

I tried to put in Extras but didn't work...

thanks for your help

> this.dhn = new DataHelper(this);

```
public void StartGame(View v) { 
Intent intent = new Intent(StartScreen.this, Game.class); 
intent.putExtra("dhn",this.dhn); 
startActivity(intent); 
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I changed my DataHelper to Singleton, looks able to use from any other intents without new helper.. looks working for now. going to test more

```
    private static DataHelper singleton;

    public static DataHelper getDataHelper(Context context) {
            if (singleton == null) {
                    singleton = new DataHelper(context);
                    OpenHelper openHelper = new OpenHelper(singleton.context);
                    singleton.db = openHelper.getWritableDatabase();
            }
            if(!singleton.db.isOpen()){
                    OpenHelper openHelper = new OpenHelper(singleton.context);
                    singleton.db = openHelper.getWritableDatabase();
            }
            singleton.context = context;
            return singleton;
    }

    private DataHelper(Context context) {
        this.context = context;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This is how I approach the problem in my code:

```
public class DataOpenHelper extends SQLiteOpenHelper
{
    private static Object lock = new Object();
    private static DataOpenHelper inst = null;
    private static Context nextContext = null;

    private DataOpenHelper()
    {
        super(nextContext);
        nextContext = null;
    }

    public static void registerContext(Context ctx)
    {
        synchronized (lock)
        {
            nextContext = ctx;
        }
    }

    public static DataOpenHelper getInstance() throws ContextNotRegisteredException
    {
        if (inst == null)
        {
            synchronized (lock)
            {
                if (inst == null)
                {
                    if (nextContext == null)
                    {
                        throw new ContextNotRegisteredException();
                    }

                    inst = new DataOpenHelper();
                }
            }
        }
    }

}

    public class ContextNotRegisteredException extends Exception{};
```